# Настенное приспособление - экран, монитор?

Tags: названия

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как называют предмет, на который проецируется картинка? Из какого он материала?

Comment: Вопросы по исправлениям. Этот предмет некорректно считать приспособлением? Траслирование - это только особого рода (средствами радио) передача изображения? Разве "транслировать" не может означать "выводить на экран"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если используется *световой* проектор, то это **экран** (отражающего типа), он бывает из бумаги, ткани (в этих случаях сворачивается в рулон), из окрашенного дерева или с покрытием из полимерного материала. В остальных случаях это (электронный) монитор или дисплей, которые преобразуют в изображение видеосигнал.